# No puedo obtener el valor de este objetoId {$oid: '62169852fbd430fa096347c9'}

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, flask

Estoy realizando una app tipo CRUD que involucra MongoDB, Flask, Reactjs. Todo ello dockerizado.

Realizo un mapeo de todas las tareas almacenadas en la base de datos, para obtener alguna en específico, actualizar o borrar. Debo de hacerlo con el `_id`. el problema sucede ya que no puedo pasarle a la API el valor de esta línea:

```
 {$oid: '62169852fbd430fa096347c9'}
```

he probado con `str`, `toHexString()`, `valueOf()` que es lo que encontré en la bibliografía y se me acabaron las opciones.

Soy nuevo y es mi primer proyecto en mi primer oportunidad laboral, agradecería mucho cualquier tipo de sugerencia..

Comment: `oid` puede ser un tipo Object ID proveniente de `mongoDB`, por favor muéstranos el codigo de lo que estas intentado hacer. saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario.. Precisamente como lo indicas, es un tipo de ObjectID y la solución la encontré accediendo al atributo dentro de dicho objeto.. y pasando este valor como parámetro a la llamada.. Saludos :)

Comment: @EmaAvalos ¡ponlo como respuesta, y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer)! Recuerda que este es un sitio de _preguntas y respuestas_ :)